# Query Button Name when clicked

Tags: loops, button, command, maya, click

In Maya:

I am building a dynamic UI which creates for each character a button with the characters name. To keep stuff simple I want to print the name of the button when it is clicked. 
I can't get it to work, because the buttons are create with just one 
btn=cmds.button('%sBtn'%character,c="print btn") line.
So when I click the button only the last created button in the for loop is printed..
Any ideas?

Comment: You should post what you have already so as to see exactly what you're dealing with. But if you want to keep things dynamic that scriptJob is pretty handy that I showed you last time. You can find some more info on how to better use it for this [here](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/CommandsPython/scriptJob.html).

Comment: Use functools partial to load stuff on the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmds.window( width=150 )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
for i in range(5):
    btnName = 'button'+str(i)
    btnCmd = ('print \'%s\'')%(btnName)
    cmds.button( btnName, label='Button 1', command=btnCmd )
cmds.showWindow()
```